# Unable to connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB - Due to trigger execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

I have a SQL Server Express instance on my machine that had been working fine and I have no idea what changed. I get this error now:

> Logon failed for login 'myusername' due to trigger execution.
> Changed database context to 'master'.

I have tried to follow this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218811/logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution

So there are many ideas about just deleting the offending trigger and you can connect with the Dedicated Admin Connection (DAC) if needed to do this. I am not having to connect through the DAC because I can connect to sa using `MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME` just fine. My problem is only when connecting with `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. For some reason LocalDB causes this error only.

When I log in with 'sa' and run this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers;
```

There are no rows returned. It is an empty result. So, where is the trigger that I need to disable? Is LocalDB not connecting to the same instance as my SQL Server Express instance or something? So, LocalDB connects to something else that has a trigger problem whereas connecting by `MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME` has no triggers. I would think that the 'sa' login would be able to see triggers if they were there.

EDIT 1:
OK. I have found all of these triggers now in the msdb database. I have checked all the databases and this is the only one that had any triggers.

syscollector_collection_item_parameter_update_trigger

syscollector_tsql_query_collector_delete_trigger

trig_targetserver_insert

syspolicy_update_system_health_state

sysmanagement_delete_shared_server_group_trigger

syspolicy_execution_trigger

trig_notification_ins_or_upd

trig_notification_delete

syspolicy_validate_events

syspolicy_insert_job_create_trigger

syspolicy_update_job_update_trigger

syspolicy_insert_policy_trigger

syspolicy_update_policy_trigger

syspolicy_delete_job_delete_trigger

syspolicy_instead_delete_policy_trigger

syspolicy_insert_condition_trigger

syspolicy_for_update_condition_trigger

trig_sysoriginatingservers_delete

syspolicy_after_update_condition_trigger

trig_sysjobs_insert_update

syscollector_collection_set_is_running_update_trigger

trig_sysmail_profile

trig_sysschedules_insert_update

trig_principalprofile

trig_sysmail_account

trig_sysmail_profileaccount

trig_backupset_delete

trig_sysmail_profile_delete

trig_sysmail_servertype

trig_sysmail_server

trig_sysmail_configuration

trig_sysmail_mailitems

syspolicy_insert_target_set_level_trigger

trig_sysmail_attachments

syspolicy_update_target_set_level_trigger

trig_sysmail_log

syspolicy_insert_target_set_trigger

syspolicy_delete_target_set_trigger

Comment: It's probably a database-level trigger `select * from sys.triggers where parent_class = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the idea @Charlieface, but `select * from sys.triggers` is returning no rows at all.

Comment: Under which database? `sys.triggers` is per database, so you would do something like `myDb.sys.triggers` or preface with `USE mydb;`

Comment: @Charlieface - Ah ha! I do have some in the msdb database. I put them all in an edit in my original question. None of them have parent_class = 0. I will try disabling them temporarily and see what happens.

Comment: Don't disable those. Hold it, `INSTANCENAME` and `MSSQLLocalDB` are different instances, which one are you logged in to?

Comment: @Charlieface - I am in INSTANCENAME. MSSQLLocalDB is where I have the problem. Hrm. I see where you are going with that I think.

Comment: OK, you need to get start up LocalDB in single user, or try get a DAC connection to it. There will be a trigger on there. By the looks of the error message, it is DB level, not server level, and will be on whatever the default DB is for that login

Comment: @Charlieface - Thanks for your help. I have now seen I have other problems now. I dont appear to even have a MSSQLLocalDB instance listed in SQL Server Configuration Manager. I don't know what happened to this thing. I was just running select queries one minute then this problem the next.

Comment: Not sure if it shows up there. Can you access it by setting the database as `master` in the connection parameters?

Comment: @Charlieface - There are no databases listed when I go to Options. If I <Browse Server...> it just gives the same error message:
TITLE: Browse Server for Database
------------------------------

Logon failed for login 'loginname' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=17892&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

Comment: @Charlieface - I should also add that I try to connect with the DAC and when I try `admin:(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` it just acts like the server doesn't exist or is inaccessible.

Comment: @Charlieface - I also tried with `Database=master` in the additional parameters

Comment: Don't think LocalDB has a DAC. I wonder if there is a way to start it in single-user mode. You may need to just [rebuld master](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver15) then re-attach your DBs

Comment: @Charlieface - I am actually in the process of reattaching all databases to the SQLEXPRESS instance. I already uninstalled and reinstalled SQL on this computer entirely.

Comment: @Charlieface - Well, I can run my app locally again with changing to my local instance. This is not ideal since it is a shared project, but we will manage with switching the connection strings when we have to debug against our local databases. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall LocalDB then. That will give you a new master DB

Comment: @Charlieface - What's funny is I already did that this morning. I just uninstalled SQL Server 2019 LocalDB again and reinstalled, then rebooted. Still the same login trigger error when connecting with `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: My experience is IDENTICAL. Same error. Uninstall LocalDB. Reinstall LocalDB. Same error. Can't figure out the cause let alone the solution.

Answer (score 41):

My solution, from an Admin Visual Studio CMD prompt:

```
SqlLocalDB stop MSSQLLocalDB -k
SqlLocalDB delete MSSQLLocalDB
SqlLocalDB create MSSQLLocalDB -s
```

> Aside: Prior to this, I upgraded to 2019 using the SQL Express installer.

Finally, my RegEdit for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Your post about these
SqlLocalDB stop MSSQLLocalDB -k
SqlLocalDB delete MSSQLLocalDB
SqlLocalDB create MSSQLLocalDB -s

was the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution!

Comment: That only resolves the symptom though - I'm running into this for third time now and still wonder what might have caused the corrupted state in the first place.

Comment: Forth time now, and still no Idea what triggers this issue

Comment: This worked for me, on Windows 11, with localdb version 15.0.4153.1

Comment: @mbx were you ever able to find out the cause?

Comment: @YitzakHernandez unfortunately not, and coming just out of vacation I just ran into that issue once more without even a clue what might caused it probably a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

When it happens on our machines, this is usually due to Visual Studio *VsCodeIndex* database being removed before removing the trigger.

Since DAC does not work, we use this method to regain access to our instances without losing any data:

1. Close all Visual Studio/Code instances to prevent race conditions on the database
2. Locate the installation directory, which should be something like `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`
3. Open the most recent log file and verify that SQL Server is indeed trying to open a non existing database. The log file near the end should be like this

```
2023-05-22 16:03:52.89 spid51      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2023-05-22 16:03:52.89 spid51      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Temp\VS11CodeIndex\Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_2f1ff123_0949_4b08_88ae_5cda46820c33.mdf for file number 0.  OS error: 3(Het systeem kan het opgegeven pad niet vinden.).
2023-05-22 16:03:52.89 spid51      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
```

3. If the log files are different, the procedure won't work
4. Create the offending path (e.g. `C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Local\Temp\VS11CodeIndex` in the example above)
5. Copy an existing database (an empty one is sufficient, we usually have a few around) in this folder and name it properly. In the example above, **MDF** is `Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_2f1ff123_0949_4b08_88ae_5cda46820c33.mdf` and the **LDF** is `Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_2f1ff123_0949_4b08_88ae_5cda46820c33_log.ldf` (be careful here, the file name ends with `_log`)
6. Now you should be able to login with SSMS
7. Navigate to *Server Objects\Triggers*
8. Delete the offending triggers. As of today, we have these two

- `Trigger_Repository_Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_Drop`
- `Trigger_Repository_Microsoft.VsCodeIndex_Repository.Item_Logon_SetSecurityClaims`

8. Delete the fake database